# Splitting the column values based on a delimiter (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda dataframe with a column name - AA_IDs. The column name values has a special character "-#" in few rows. I need to determine three things:

1. Position of these special characters or delimiters
2. find the string before the special character
3. Find the string after the special character

E.g. AFB001 9183Daily-#789876A

Answer would be before the delimiter - `AFB001 9183Daily` and after the delimiter - `789876A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use apply function with split -

```
df['AA_IDs'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-#'))
```

This should give you a series with a list for each row as `[AFB001 9183Daily, 789876A]`

This would be significantly faster than using regex, and not to mention the readability.

Comment: Thanks so much. Will it still work if there are multiple delimiters? The next part of the code is to create a dataframe column with the string names that I just splitted. I need to repeat this process of splitting columns for several times. Any suggestions to make it faster?

Comment: You can replace all the delimiters with a single delimiter and then split on that - ```str.replace('; ', ', ')``` and then ```str.split(', ')```

Comment: Oh, that is a brilliant idea. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

So lets say the dataframe is called `df` and the column with the text is `A`.
You can use

```py
import re # Import regex

pattern = r'<your regex>'

df['one'] = df.A.str.extract(pattern)
```

This creates a new column containing the extracted text. You just need to create a regex to extract what you want from your string(s). I highly recommend [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to help you construct your regex.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! I am not very familiar with the regex process, so I will go through the process.